# Delete data from three different tables using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I implemented a project in Yii. I want to delete data from table using ajax function.

In my controller I wrote this:

```
public function actionDelete1(){
    if (isset($_POST['x1']) && isset($_POST['r_id'])) {
        $hid=$_POST['x1'];
        $rid=$_POST['r_id'];

        echo $_POST['x1'].'recipe_id'.$_POST['r_id'];

        $query="delete from ingredients  where ingredienttype_id='$hid'";
        $query1=Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($query)->execute();

        $this->redirect(array('recipe/update','id'=>$rid));
    }

}
```

In my view part:

```
<script>
function removeRow1(x,y){    
    alert("Are sure want to delete");

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("ingredients/delete1"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'x1='+x+'&r_id='+y,
        success: function(res)
        {
            //alert(res);
            ////$("#truth").html(res);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Failed request data from ajax page");
        }
    });    
}
</script>
```

I display these three table data with one row:

```
<td id="data">
    <?php 
        echo $i++; 
    ?>
</td>
<td id="data">
    <?php  
        $type=Ingredienttype::model()->find("id=$type_id");
        echo $type['ingredient_type'];  
    ?>
</td>
<td id="data">
    <?php 
        $type1=Ingredient::model()->find("ingredient_id=$ingredient_id"); 
        //echo $ingredient_id;
        echo $type1['ingredientname']; 
    ?>
</td>
<td id="data">
    <?php 
        echo $quantity; 
    ?>
</td>
<td id="data">
    <?php 
        $mes_type=Measuringtype::model()->find("id=$measuringtype");
        echo  $mes_type['measuringname']; 
    ?>
</td>

<input type="button" id="<?php echo $type_id; ?>" name="doesntMatter" class="REMOVETHIS btn btn-inverse btn-xs" 
                value="Del" onclick="removeRow1(this.id,<?php echo $model->recipe_id ?>)"/></td>
```

It's not working. Please suggest me how to delete ID using ajax.

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: Well, "dude" , obviously if everything was working fine you wouldn't be here. Could you tell us more about the problem ? Is it failing silently ? Is it breaking the space-time continuum ? Is there an error message ? Is the error client-side or server-side ? At which point does the error occur (when sending the data, when processing it on the server, when processing the response, ... ?) ? You know, all these things we can't just guess...

Comment: am not getting any error.

Comment: as well as same operation working on another table. same thing i implemented here. its not working

Comment: There appears to be an extra `</td>` after your `<input>`. Is that miscopied code, or is that actually what it looks like?

Comment: That is very helpfull... so you don't have any error, and another code that we don't see is working. The I would say that the problem resides in the differences between your working code and your non-working one.  Have you considered comparing them ? Not that this little "guess my problem" game isn't funny, but still...

Answer (score 1):

First you have

```
$query="delete from ingredients  where ingredienttype_id='$hid'";
```

where `$hid` is not defined yet!

Would you use either `$hid` or `$rid` ?

Secondly, sending params with ajax, data should be an object, I don't know if it works with a string. so to be sure, try using an object as follows

```
  $.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("ingredients/delete1"); ?>',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'x1':x,'r_id':y},
  success: function(res)
  {
    //----
```